# Javascript variable to Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am using this code:

```
set javaScriptVar to "var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement; var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight); return height"

set myJSvar to do JavaScript javaScriptVar in document 1

display alert myJSvar
```

And the value I am getting is: `msng`
What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set javaScriptVar to "var body = document.body; html = document.documentElement; var height = Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight); height;"

tell application "Safari" to set myJSvar to do JavaScript javaScriptVar in document 1
```